# Output the Juggler sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, number-theory

The [Juggler sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juggler_sequence) is described as follows. Beginning with an input \$a_1\$, the next term is defined by the recurrence relation

$$a_{k+1} = \begin{cases}
\left\lfloor a_k ^ \frac 1 2 \right\rfloor,\text{ if } a_k \text{ is even} \\
\left\lfloor a_k ^ \frac 3 2 \right\rfloor,\text{ if } a_k \text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases}$$

The sequence terminates when it reaches 1, as all subsequent terms would then be 1.

### Task

Given an input \$n\$ greater than or equal to 2, write a program/function/generator/etc. that outputs/returns the respective juggler sequence. The output can be in any reasonable form. You may not use a built-in that computes the juggler sequence, or any built-in that directly yields the result. You may assume that the sequence terminates in \$1\$.

### Test Cases

```
Input: output
2: 2, 1
3: 3, 5, 11, 36, 6, 2, 1
4: 4, 2, 1
5: 5, 11, 36, 6, 2, 1
```

This is a code golf. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I got a little nerd sniped and computed the number of steps to halt for the first `~5.6*10^7` values (they all halt so far).

Comment: Reminds me of the Collatz conjecture (still unsolved)

Comment: @wim yes, it's very similar to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
*BṪ×½Ḟµ’Ð¿
```

*Thanks to @Sp3000 for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KkLhuarDl8K94biewrXigJnDkMK_&input=&args=Mw)

#### How it works

```
*BṪ×½Ḟµ’Ð¿    Main link. Input: n

*B            Elevate n to all of its digits in base 2.
  Ṫ           Extract the last power.
              This yields n ** (n % 2).
   ×½         Multiply with sqrt(n). This yields n ** (n % 2 + 0.5).
     Ḟ        Floor.

      µ       Push the previous chain on the stack and begin a new, monadic chain.
        Ð¿    Repeat the previous chain while...
       ’        n - 1 is non-zero.
              Collect all intermediate results in an array.
```

Comment: I'm almost afraid asking, since the poster has 87k reputation, but is it really possible to represent this in 10 bytes? You're using 10 characters, but can you really fit all of these very esoteric characters into only 256 combinations? ½, Ḟ, Ð would not seem to be my first choices for characters to add into my alphabet, considering I only have 256 places to fill...

Comment: @Annonymus Jelly uses a [custom code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) that encodes each of the 256 characters it understands as a sinlge byte each.

Comment: I see! Thanks. Btw, I found a bug in your table, character 20 (I'm assuming it's a space, if it isn't the "bug" is that this is unclear) gets removed since it is a lonely space, you should use &nbsp; instead.

Comment: @Annonymus Yes, that looked a little weird. I didn't want to use NBSP since any attempt to copy the table would break, but `<code> </code>` instead of the backticks seems to display an actual SP character. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 10):

## Julia, <s>64</s> <s>50</s> <s>48</s> <s>42</s> <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
g(x)=[x;x<3||g(x^(x%2+.5)÷1)]
```

This is a recursive function that accepts an integer and returns a float array.

We build an array by concatenating the input with the next term of the sequence, computed as *x* to the power of its parity plus 1/2. This gives us either *x*<sup>1/2</sup> or *x*<sup>1+1/2</sup> = *x*<sup>3/2</sup>. Integer division by 1 gets the floor. When the condition *x* < 3 is true, the final element will be a Boolean rather than a numeric value, but since the array is not of type `Any`, this is cast to have the same type as the rest of the array.

Saved 14 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Comment: Can the Julia interpreter handle source code in ISO 8859-1? Then the integer division would only be a single byte.

Comment: @MartinBüttner No, I've tried it before and it got pretty mad. Julia's parser assumes UTF-8.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>45</s> 33 bytes

```js
f=n=>n<2?n:n+","+f(n**(.5+n%2)|0)
```

### Explanation

Recursive approach. Returns a comma-separated string of numbers.

```
f=n=>
  n<2?n:          // stop when n == 1
  n               // return n at the start of the list
  +","+f(         // add the rest of the sequence to the list
    n**(.5+n%2)|0 // juggler algorithm
  )
```

### Test

`**` not used in test for browser compatibility.

```js
f=n=>n<2?n:n+","+f(Math.pow(n,.5+n%2)|0)
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="result.textContent=f(+this.value)" />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I sure wish `**` were supported in all browsers.

Comment: @ETHproductions I sure wish `**`  were supported in C#.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>40</s> 39 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Büttner for saving 1 byte.*

```
NestWhileList[⌊#^.5#^#~Mod~2⌋&,#,#>1&]&
```

**Test case**

```
%[5]
(* {5,11,36,6,2,1} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

## MATL, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
`tt2\.5+^ktq
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YHR0MlwuNSteWm90cQ&input=NQ)

Explanation

```
`     % do...while loop
tt   % duplicate top of stack twice, takes implicit input on first iteration
2\    % take a_k mod 2
.5+^  % adds 0.5, to give 1.5 if odd, 0.5 if even, and takes a_k^(0.5 or 1.5)
kt    % Rounds down, and duplicates
q     % Decrement by 1 and use for termination condition---if it is 0, loop will finish
```

Thanks Luis for saving a byte!

Comment: The `floor` function has been changed to `k`, so you can use that instead of `Zo` to save 1 byte. (Sorry for these changes; you can see the release summaries [here](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases))

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
.us@*B@N2NNQ
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.us%40%2aB%40N2NNQ&input=3&debug=0)

We start with a cumulative reduce, `.u`, which in this case starts at the input and applies a function until the result repeats, at which point it outputs all of the intermediate results.

The function takes the previous value as `N`. It starts by taking its square root with `@N2`. Next, it bifurcates that value on multiplication by `N` with `*B ... N`. This creates the list `[N ** .5, (N ** .5) * N]`, the unfloored results for the even and odd cases. Next, the appropriate unfloored result is selected by indexing into the list with `@ ... N`. Since Pyth has modular indexing, no out-of-bounds errors are thrown. Finally, the result is floored with `s`.

Answer (score 5):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 25 bytes

```
ndN(d$7;r2%2*1+;YdNd1=,).
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=ndN%28d%247%3Br2%252*1%2B%3BYdNd1%3D%2C%29%2E&input=3)

#### Explanation

```
n                            Take number from input => n
 dN                          Duplicate and output as number
   (                         Open while loop
    d                        Duplicate top of stack => n, n
     $7                      Push 0.5
       ;                     Pop b,a and push a**b => n, sqrt(n)
        r                    Reverse stack => sqrt(n), n
         2%                  Modulo by 2
           2*                Multiply by 2
             1+              Add 1 => sqrt(n), [1 if even, 3 if odd]
               ;             Pop b,a and push a**b => sqrt(n)**{1,3}
                Y            Floor top of stack
                 dN          Duplicate and output as number
                   d1=,      Duplicate and => 0 if 1, 1 otherwise
                       ).    Pop top of stack and end while loop if 0, then stop.
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL, <s>28</s> <s>24</s> 16 bytes

```
{⌊⍵*.5+2|⎕←⍵}⍣=⎕
```

This is a program that accepts an integer and prints the successive outputs on separate lines.

Explanation:

```
{           }⍣=⎕   ⍝ Apply the function until the result is the input
 ⌊⍵*.5+2|⎕←⍵       ⍝ Print the input, compute floor(input^(input % 2 + 0.5))
```

[Try it online](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%7B%u230A%u2375*.5+2%7C%u2395%u2190%u2375%7D%u2363%3D%u2395)

Saved 8 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 3):

### TSQL, 89 bytes

Input goes in `@N`:

```
DECLARE @N INT = 5;
```

Code:

```
WITH N AS(SELECT @N N UNION ALL SELECT POWER(N,N%2+.5) N FROM N WHERE N>1)SELECT * FROM N
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java 7, <s>83</s> 71 bytes

```
void g(int a){System.out.println(a);if(a>1)g((int)Math.pow(a,a%2+.5));}
```

I originally used a typical `for` loop, but I had to jump through hoops to get it working right. After <s>stealing</s> borrowing [user81655's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73138/14215) to recurse instead, I got it down twelve bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>57</s>, <s>45</s>, <s>43</s>, 41 bytes

Better Solution with suggestion from @mathmandan

```
def a(n):print(n);n<2or a(n**(.5+n%2)//1)
```

This method will print each number on a new line

Previous Solution: Cut down to 43 bytes after xnor's recommendation

```
a=lambda n:[n][:n<2]or[n]+a(n**(n%2+.5)//1)
```

You can call the above by doing `a(10)` which returns `[10, 3.0, 5.0, 11.0, 36.0, 6.0, 2.0, 1.0]`

The above will output the values as floats. If you want them as integers, then we can just add an extra 2 bytes for 43 bytes:

```
def a(n):print(n);n<2or a(int(n**(.5+n%2)))
```

Comment: It's a bit shorter to handle the base case by doing `[n][:n<2]or`, or as `1/n*[n]or` for the integer case.

Comment: Using Python 2, you can get it down to 41 bytes with `def j(n):print n;n-1and j(n**(.5+n%2)//1)`.  (Or in Python 3, `def j(n):print(n);n-1and j(n**(.5+n%2)//1)` is 42 bytes.) It'll print the sequence term by term instead of collecting the terms in a list.

Comment: I can also remove another byte off that by doing `n<2or` rather than `n-1and`

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>54</s>  51 bytes

```
z=n=scan();while(n>1){n=n^(.5+n%%2)%/%1;z=c(z,n)};z
```

Saved 3 bytes thanks to plannapus.

Comment: Given that all n are positive, one can shorten `floor(n^(.5+n%%2))` to `n^(.5+n%%2)%/%1` I think. +1 Nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 70 bytes

Haskell doesn't have integer `sqrt` built-in, but I think there may be something shorter than `floor.sqrt.fromInteger`.

```
s=floor.sqrt.fromInteger
f n|odd n=s$n^3|1<2=s n
g 1=[1]
g n=n:g(f n)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 128 bytes

```
WITH v(i)AS(SELECT :1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT FLOOR(DECODE(MOD(i,2),0,SQRT(i),POWER(i,1.5)))FROM v WHERE i>1)SELECT i FROM v;
```

Un-golfed

```
WITH v(i) AS
(
  SELECT :1 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
--  SELECT FLOOR(POWER(i,0.5+MOD(i,2))) FROM v WHERE i>1
  SELECT FLOOR(DECODE(MOD(i,2),0,SQRT(i),POWER(i,1.5))) FROM v WHERE i>1 
)
SELECT * FROM v;
```

Adding MOD(i,2) to .5 is shorter but there is a bug with POWER(2,.5) :

```
SELECT POWER(4,.5), FLOOR(POWER(4,.5)), TO_CHAR(POWER(4,.5)) FROM DUAL
```

gives

```
2   1   1,99999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 18 bytes

```
ri{__2%.5+#i_(}g]p
```

[**Test it here**](http://goo.gl/qI5alq)

Similar to [David's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73131/36398).

Answer (score 2):

### TI-Basic, 30 Bytes

```
Prompt A
Repeat A=1
Disp A
int(A^(remainder(A,2)+.5->A
End
1
```

Comment: 22 bytes if you take input from Ans, replace `Repeat Ans=1` with `While log(Ans`, and use `√(Ans)Ans^remainder(Ans,2`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
λ∷d›½e⌊;İJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLOu+KIt2TigLrCvWXijIo7xLBKIiwiIiwiNSJd)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>109</s> 102 bytes

```
s=>(f=n=>n==1?n:n%2?Math.pow(n,3/2)|0:Math.sqrt(n)|0,a=[s],eval("while(f(s)-1)a.push(s=f(s))"),a+",1")
```

I *know* this can be golfed. Returns a string of comma-separated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 122 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
void f(int n){int i;while(n^1){std::cout<<n<<',';for(i=n*n;i*i>(n%2?n*n*n:n);i--);n=i;}std::cout<<1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>64</s> <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```c
t;q(n){for(;!t;n=pow(n,.5+n%2))printf("%d%c ",n,n^1?44:t++);}
```

Comment: You can replace `n%2?1.5:0.5` with `n%2+0.5` or `.5+n%2` (if C allows it). If `n%2` is true,  `n%2` is 1, else 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 144 bytes

Input and output are in unary.

The 2nd-to-last line contains a space, and the two middle lines and the last line are empty.

```
{`(\b|)11+$
$&¶$&
m-1=`^(?=^(11)*(1?)).*$
$&,$2
(1+),1$
$1;,
1(?=1*;)
$%_
1+;
$%_
;|,

m-1=`^
1:
+`(1+):(11\1)
1 $2:
1+:$|:1+

-1=`(1+\b)
$#1
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=e2AoXGJ8KTExKyQKJCbCtiQmCm0tMT1gXig_PV4oMTEpKigxPykpLiokCiQmLCQyCigxKyksMSQKJDE7LAoxKD89MSo7KQokJV8KMSs7CiQlXwo7fCwKCm0tMT1gXgoxOgorYCgxKyk6KDExXDEpCjEgJDI6CjErOiR8OjErCgotMT1gKDErXGIpCiQjMQogCg&input=MTEx)

#### Explanation

```
{`(\b|)11+$                 # Loop, Duplicate last line
$&¶$&
m-1=`^(?=^(11)*(1?)).*$     # Append ,n%2 to that line (number modulo 2)
$&,$2
(1+),1$                     # Cube that number if odd
$1;,
1(?=1*;)
$%_
1+;
$%_
;|,                         # (Last stage of cubing number)

m-1=`^                      # Integer square root of that number, 
1:                          #   borrowed and modified from another user's answer
+`(1+):(11\1)
1 $2:
1+:$|:1+

-1=`(1+\b)
$#1
```

[Integer square root in Retina](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82632/34718), by  Digital Trauma

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>14</s></sup> 12 bytes

```
U¡o⌊?^1.5√%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/TQwvxHPV32cYZ6po86Zqka/f//3xQA)

### Explanation

```
U¡ȯ⌊?^1.5√%2
 ¡             iterate over the input infinitely, creating a list
  ȯ            with the following three functions:
               take the previous result
          %2   modulo 2
    ?^1.5      if truthy, raise to 3/2th power
         √     else take square root
   ⌊           floor the result
U              cut the list at fixed point
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δ=DÉ·>;mï
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

Outputs each result on a separate line.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3BQX28Odh7bbWeceXv//vzEA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R8ZcnRHmZJnXkFpiZWCkn2lDpeSf2kJhKdT@f/cFFuXw52HtttZ5x5e/7/20Db7/wA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ          # Loop until the result no longer changes:
 =         #  Print the current value with trailing newline (without popping)
           #  (which will be the implicit input-integer in the first iteration)
  D        #  Duplicate the value
   É       #  Pop the copy, and check if it's odd (1 if odd; 0 if even)
    ·      #  Double that
     >     #  Increase it by 1
      ;    #  Halve it
       m   #  Take the current value to the power this 1/2 or 3/2
        ï  #  And then cast it to an integer to floor it
```

Comment: By combining fixed-point and manual printing, this get a bit shorter: [`ΔD=É·>;mï`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3BQX28Odh7bbWeceXv//vzEA).

Comment: @ovs Ah nice. I hadn't thought about printing the results on separated newlines. That would have also resulted in a 10-byter in the infinite loop approach. But your 9-byter is even better by combining the fixed-point and printing indeed, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
*Ḃ×½ḞµƬ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r4Y6mw9MP7X24Y96hrcfW/D/cnvWocZ@OwsOda0EMKwXNyP//jXQUjHUUTHUUzAA)

Basically Dennis' method, but updated to use the modern version of Jelly. I initially had [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r4Y6mhzuWPGqY4XFs08Md8451HVvzX@dwe9ajxn06Cse6QLSVgmbk//9GOgrGOgqmOgpmAA), but switching to the `×½` method saved 2 bytes.

### How it works

```
*Ḃ×½ḞµƬ - Main link. Takes n on the left
     µ  - Group the previous links into a monad f(n):
 Ḃ      -   Bit; n % 2
*       -   n ** (n % 2)
   ½    -   n ** (1 / 2)
  ×     -   n ** (n % 2 + 1 / 2)
    Ḟ   -   Floor
      Ƭ - Repeatedly apply f(n), yielding [n, f(n), f(f(n)), ..., 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 52 bytes

```factor
[ [ 3 dupn . odd? 3/2 .5 ? ^ 1 /i dup 1 > ] loop . ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCsIwEAXv/Yr3BSkavCjYo3jxUjyVCkuSajBuwro96M/HqrdhZiZymqWe@@PpsMU1cBBK8U0aMz9xD8Ih4UF6Q5Gg@ioSWX/CTDO7/7ZrGlsHDLDwc2EYZO872HYNs0GHC1Zo47ctsMeIlHNZrrE6Sql@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 49 bytes

```lua
b=...repeat a=b print(a)b=b^(.5+b%2)//1until a==b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/yVZPT68otSA1sUQh0TZJoaAoM69EI1EzyTYpTkPPVDtJ1UhTX9@wNK8kMweowDbp////xgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 55 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.875 bytes

```
∷.+e⌊)↔
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oi3Litl4oyKKeKGlCIsIiIsIjMiXQ==)

### Explained

```
∷.+e⌊)↔­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
     )↔  # ‎⁡Generate until fixed point, starting with the input:
∷.+      # ‎⁢  Add the bit parity of the argument to 0.5 (0.5 if even, 1.5 if odd)
   e     # ‎⁣  And raise the argument to that number
    ⌊    # ‎⁤  Floor it.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7.5 bytes (15 nibbles)

```
`.$^^$^3%$~-2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWaxP0VOLiVOKMVVXqdI0gYlCppdFKxkqxUA4A)

```
`.              # iterate while unique
  $             # starting with input:
        %$~     #  result-so-far modulo-2
      ^3        #  3 to the power of that (so: 3 or 1)
    ^$          #  result-so-far to the power of that
   ^       -2   #  floor square-root
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI BASIC, 43 bytes

I'm pulling a Thomas Kwa and answering this one on my mobile.

```
Input N
Repeat N=1
Disp N
remainder(N,2->B
If not(B:int(sqrt(N->N
If B:int(N^1.5->N
End
1
```

Replace `sqrt` with the actual symbol on your calculator. Displays a linefeed separated list of numbers, which is a reasonable format.

Comment: You can golf this more.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yeah, you're probably right. I'll think about it for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, 76 bytes

Is a generator named `j`. To use, set `a = j(<your value>);`. To see the next value in the sequence, enter `a.next().value`.

```
function*j(N){for(yield N;N-1;)yield N=(N%2?Math.pow(N,3/2):Math.sqrt(N))|0}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function* juggler(N){
    yield N;
    while(N!=1){
        N = Math.floor(N % 2 ? Math.pow(N,3/2) : Math.sqrt(N));
        yield N;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 62 bytes

```
string f(int n)=>n+(n<2?"":","+f((int)Math.Pow(n,.5+n%2)));
```

Inspired by @user81655 and @Alex A., I used recursion.

Answer (score 0):

## dc, <del>22</del> 21 bytes

```
[pd2%2*1+^vd1<F]dsFxn
```

Explained:

```
[                # Begin macro definition
 p               # Peek at top of stack (print without popping, followed by newline)
 d               # Duplicate top of stack
 2%              # Mod 2: If even, 0; if odd, 1
 2*1+            # If even: 0*2+1==1; if odd: 1*2+1==3
 ^v              # Raise, then square root: equivalent to `^(0.5)' or `^(1.5)'
 d1<F            # If result is not 1, run macro again
]dsFx            # Duplicate macro, store as `F', execute
n                # Print the final "1"
```

There's a bug: When the input is `1`, the output consists of two `1`s.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 34 bytes

33, plus 1 for `-pE` instead of `-e`

```
say;($_=int$_**($_%2+.5))-1&&redo
```

### Explanation

First, `-p` sets the variable `$_` equal to the input from stdin. Then we start a block of code:

> 1. [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) prints `$_`.
> 2. `$_=int$_**($_%2+.5)` sets `$_` equal to the integer part of {`$_` to the power of {{`$_` modulo 2} + 0.5}}, due to the magic of order of operations ([operator precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)). This assignment returns the new value of `$_`, and
> 3. `(...)-1&&redo` tests that returned value, minus 1. If the difference is 0, do nothing; otherwise, redo this block.

Finally, `-p` prints `$_`.

### Of equal length

Also uses `-p`.

```
say()-($_=int$_**($_%2+.5))&&redo
```

This: prints `$_`; assigns as above; tests whether the return value of `say` (which is 1), minus the new value of `$_`, is 0, and redoes the block if so; then prints `$_` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

## F# 77 bytes

Doesn't terminate at 1, but keeps going.

```
let j=Seq.unfold(fun x->Some(x,floor(match x%2. with 0.->x**0.5|1.->x**1.5)))
```

Usage:

```
j 3.;;
> val it : seq<float> = seq [3.0; 5.0; 11.0; 36.0; ...]
```

Version that actually terminates at 1, 100 bytes

```
let j=Seq.unfold(fun x->if x=1. then None else Some(x,floor(match x%2. with 0.->x**0.5|1.->x**1.5)))
```

Ungolfed

```
let juggle input =
    let next x = 
        floor
            (match x % 2. with 
                | 0. -> x ** 0.5
                | 1. -> x ** 1.5
                | _ -> failwith "this should never happen") // addressing a compiler warning
    Seq.unfold (fun x -> if x = 1. then None else Some(x, next x)) input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 30 bytes

```
{$_,{floor $_**(.5+$_%2)}...1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiVepzotJz@/SEElXktLQ89UWyVe1UizVk9Pz7D2f3FipYKSSryCrZ1CdRpQRa2SQhpQqZGenul/AA)

This anonymous function returns the sequence of Juggler numbers.  `{ floor $_ ** (.5 + $_ % 2) }` evaluates each successive term of the sequence, the `floor` of the previous number `$_` raised to a power which is one-half plus the that number modulo 2.